# Loss of cookies in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, prestashop, session-cookies

I send the user to the bank site for online payment.
After the user returned from the bank site to my site, the site cookies were completely removed.
This problem has occurred to me recently and is not a problem in Firefox browser.
What is the cause of this problem?
My site is with PrestaShop

Answer (score 0):

If this issue only persist in Chrome, i am guessing it could be an issue with Chrome disabling "SameSite" cookies as default value.

**Allow cross-origin cookies:**

go to /yourstore/.htaccess and add on top of this file the code `SameSite=None`

*Make sure to clear your brower cookies*

More details about SameSite cookies can be [found here](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/)

Comment: my server is nginx 
i entered the following setting in nginx
(proxy_cookie_path ~^/(.+)$ "/$1; SameSite=None";) 
(add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;) 
, but the problem remains 
, i disabled (block third party cookies) in chrome but have no effect

Comment: @aliabdolhoseini does this issue only appears in Chrome? If so you need to keep looking to fix your .htaccess. This issue is know by Prestashop and was causing issues on the addons store where people where using the demo's trough Iframe's which where not able to login. So if the issue is only on Chrome = Issue with SameSite resolve it by adding to .htaccess manually, clear your Chrome cookies after.